# Translate Resource File

Tags: asp.net, resources, translation

I'm developing a asp.net application and I use some components. I have a component with a resource file with a lot of keys in English. I need to translate it to Portuguese (Brazil, pt-br). I would like to know, if is there any way to translate it with a program? Or if is there a program that do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issues and was looking to use Google's Translation APIs, based on this article [Automatic Resource File Translation via Google Translate](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/automatic-resource-file)

I will let you know how it goes - but obviously you may still need someone to validate the output, I know I will.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my free [Zeta Resource Editor](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ZetaResourceEditor.aspx) is of some help for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been satisfied with the various solutions out there so I wrote something: https://github.com/ekkis/Powershell/blob/master/MT.ps1